# flyway validate and future migrations

Tags: flyway

I'm new to flyway so maybe I just don't understand how `validate()` works. I creates a baseline to the database, created a migrations file `V1_2_3__do_something.sql` then ran

```
flyway validate
```

and I get

> ERROR: Validate failed: Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 1.2.3

I'm using version 4.1.0, and testing with and without the parameter `-ignoreFutureMigrations=true`, but still the same result.

Also, if I run `flyway migrate` the migration completes with not problem.

Any idea of what's happening? After the first migration, if I create a `V2__xxx` migration, then run validate again it will fail on V2 for the same reason.

Thanks

a

Answer (score 2):

Validate fails in this case because there is a pending migration. To makes it pass add `-target=current` as documented here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/validate#target

Comment: Thanks. It worked. If I can make a suggestion (and get the SO monitor's blood boiling), an `ignorePendingMigrations` option would be nice. It would be equivalent to `target=current`, but easier for new users to figure out.

Comment: Thanks it's working, in my case I am using Maven Flyway plugin, so I used this configuration `<target>current</target>` in pom.xml.